# Dropwizard Yaml for graphite server configuration

Tags: yaml, nested-lists, metrics, dropwizard, graphite

I am using metrics with dropwizard and I am reporting these to the graphite server. Almost the same way described in the tutorial. 
https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/graphite/#manual-graphite
But I wanted to configure the graphite properties in the dropwizard yaml file. Something like the following

```
metrics:
  reporters:
   - type: graphite
     host: graphite_server
     port: 2003 
     prefix: some_example_metrics
```

How do I then configure this in my dropwizard configuration class in order to use it in the application ?

Comment: A little late but: [the documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#graphite-reporter) says that you have to add `dropwizard-metrics-graphite` to your `pom.xml`.