# Reading metrics configuration from YAML file within a dropwizard REST application

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

My Metrics configuration goes like this in my dropwizard rest application, (hello-world.yml)

```
metrics:
  reporters:
    - type: log
      logger: metrics
      markerName: <marker name>
```

This one is a SLF4J Reporter I have places this in my YAML config file. Now that when I want to fetch this value and use it in my Application file. The only option i see is to read this as `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>> metrics;` What is the correct way to read this configuration and use it in the dropwizard Application class. Please help me out.

This issue is same as [Dropwizard Yaml for graphite server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432586/dropwizard-yaml-for-graphite-server-configuration). But again no answer to that question hence trying my luck by creating a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question in dropwizard user and got the answer. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/yxceCS1CEns

```
 final ImmutableList<ReporterFactory> reporters = configuration.getMetricsFactory().getReporters();
        final Slf4jReporterFactory slf4jReporterFactory = (Slf4jReporterFactory) reporters.get(0);
        slf4jReporterFactory.getMarkerName();
        slf4jReporterFactory.getLoggerName();
```